# Getting the maximum value from filtered values in pandas DataFrames? - Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to Filter the days to Monday and get the maximum OverallGrade got on Mondays.
Alternatively I have made a new Data frame for it and it shows the intended answer 90, but is there a way to do this without creating a new Data Frame?

When seeing the end result i need to see the student id also as shown in the alt solution!
Also I do not want to use days as the index and reset the index again for this purpose! ( I actually have the days as dates and do not want to use them as the index, just converted to Day names here for simplicity)

```
import pandas as pd

ClassData = {
  "Days":         ["Monday","Wednesday","Monday","Friday","Tuesday","Monday","Friday"],
  "OverallMarks": [   150,     140,       180,      250,      200 ,    240,     170  ],
  "OverallGrade": [    70,      60,        90,      110,       85 ,     80,      71  ],
  "StudentID" :   ['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
}

MyDataFrame1 = pd.DataFrame(ClassData)

# Alternate Solution I use - Creating a new Dataframe for only the mondays
NewDataFrame = MyDataFrame1[ MyDataFrame1['Days'] == "Monday" ] # Gets all Mondays
print( NewDataFrame[ NewDataFrame['OverallGrade'] == int(NewDataFrame['OverallGrade'].max()) ][['StudentID','OverallGrade']] ) 
# Gets max grade as 90 and shows the student id and grade
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First select on "Monday", just like you did
- Then sort it descending, based on the 'OverallGrade'
- Select the first element

```
print( MyDataFrame1[ MyDataFrame1['Days'] == "Monday" ].sort_values(by='OverallGrade', ascending=False).iloc[0])
```

Comment: Thank You ! Thats a new thing I learnt today !
Just to clarify my curiosity I tried putting by=['OverallMarks', 'OverallGrade'] , does it serve any purpose? 
When it sorts by OverallMarks does OverallGrade do anything here?

Comment: pd.sort_values() (see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) allows to sort on multiple columns. That means it will first sort on the first supplied column. If there are equal values after sorting, it will sort on the second supplied column, etc...